# Where to find Zoltan Chivay?

Tags: the-witcher

I'm currently pursuing the 'Memory of the blade' quest. And I'm told by Shani to talk to Zoltan about the silver sword. I found him at the Hairy Bear Inn a few times before but now I can't find him no matter at what time of the day I enter the inn. What are the other possible places that he can be in? The map does a poor job of pointing to an NPC's live location as it's always pointing to the inn even when he's not in there!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I remember that I've also found him in the room where Vivaldi (the long bearded dwarf) stayed.  He seems to wander between that area and the inn.

The [wiki](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Zoltan_Chivay) confirms:

> Later in the game, Zoltan can be found wandering around the Temple Quarter (roughly from 8:00 a.m. to 8:00 p.m.) and, if choosing to side with the Scoia'tael or take the neutral path, in the Old Vizima. **He also often spends time with Golan Vivaldi.**

Answer (score 2):

Found him at Vivaldi's place at 10:30 am.

Comment: This seems to be an answer to me.  The already existing answer does already have this information and more, though, so it's not the best answer.  Welcome to Gaming.SE, Nearga, check out the [tour](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) if you haven't already, and I hope you enjoy your stay!

Answer (score 2):

You can find him:

1. at Vivaldi's place at 11:30 am.
2. walking in the path marked below between 9:00 and 10:00 am:

[image: Zoltan Chivay walking path]